# What is the error return value of a JD Edwards calculated table with multiple return segments?

Tags: enterpriseone

We're trying to implement an Assembly Inclusion Rule in JD Edwards EnterpriseOne 9.1, by using a calculated table that returns multiple segments. It seems to work fine when the table has a valid entry for the input segments, but when an invalid input is given, the return segments seem to be blank, instead of the normal error character.

In most cases this is fine, but if I want to use this return value in a Cross-Segment Editing Rule to detect an error, it doesn't respond to comparing it to *BLANK.

Example:

- I have a table, using 3 inputs and 2 outputs.
- One of the outputs is a color, and is placed into a calculated segment.
- If the inputs are valid, they will be found in the table, and we can use the calculated color segment to create a smart part.
- If the inputs are invalid, I want to display an error message to the user. Previously, we'd use a return value of 1 (error) in a Cross Segment Editing Rule. Now that it is blank, how do I test for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is actually Blank, or better yet, "Do Not Change What Was There".

This is similar to a parts or routing table where multiple parts or routing steps are returned. If there is no match in the input segments, nothing is returned.

For calculation tables, this could be a problem, since there is no way to detect an error. Unless... you set the error flag yourself first.

Going back to the example in the question, suppose the three input segments are S1, S2, and S3, and let's assume the output segments are S101 and S102. The calculated table has a name of C.0001.

The easiest way is to make the configured item a one-pass item. This works immediately, but it is a deprecated feature, so we'll try to use static calculation.

We want to fire the rule when one of the input segments change, and set the output segments to "error" before calling the calculation table. We test the input segments by comparing them to a value they'll never get, or even *BLANK (it seems as long as they appear in the test, this works).

So, here's the C rules we use to make all this work:

```
I ( S1   NE 'XYZ'
O   S2   NE 'XYZ'
O   S3   NE *BLANK )
*   S101 EQ 1
*   S102 EQ 2
*              C.0001
```

This seems to work in all cases we've tested. Let me know if there are circumstances this doesn't work in, or you know a better way of doing this!